# How to make updatable custom Wordpress theme?

Tags: theme-development, themes, updates

I am building a custom theme and I want to make it updatable. 
The theme is made for my purposes only so it would not be present on the official repository and might be used for multiple clients.

Also, I would like avoiding using git for this purpose if possible.

I am thinking of maybe, if possible, having some private repository which stores the theme and every time there is an update of the theme within that repository all my Wordpress websites would ask me if I want to update the theme.

Is there any process of doing it? How to do it?

Comment: There are 101 ways of doing this, with various trade offs, ranging from libraries to webhooks and git pulls, you're going to need to be more specific about what you mean by a private repository, and the method you want to use. Additionally, you'll need to clarify what you mean by updating, e.g. do you mean auto-updating? Or do you mean you want to integrate with the built in WP update mechanism the same way .org theme updates work? Right now this question has a huge scope of numerous possible answers, but you need to be be able to pick 1 answer, and it has to be canonical

Comment: I don't want auto updates, but I want WP to tell me if there is update available just as with usual themes. As said, I would prefer not to use git - i.e. git pull.  The more native functionality the better.